# AutoMapper not working **Probably failing for navigation properties**

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have two classes:

> Class - Country >> ID, Name, List
>
> Class - City >> ID, Name, CountryID, Country

I have CountryViewModel and CityViewModel classes identical to the above classes.

I have written following in Global.asax.cs:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Country,CountryViewModel>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<City,CityViewModel>();
```

After retrieving entities from datbabse, I am firing following line to map models to view models.:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(country, System.Type.GetType("Country"), System.Type.GetType("CountryViewModel"));
```

This is giving "object reference not found" error on above line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure that your global.asax.cs also includes a call to `AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` to make sure everything is mapped properly.
2. I've never used the non-generic syntax for `Map` before, but the generic version that should work is:

   `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Country, CountryViewModel>(country);`